# Get direct children with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with some nested tables ( this is outputted but a dotnet control i cant do anything about )

What i want is to move all the rows that are a direct child but so far its not working as I thought it would.

I have a basic setup that just takes all the rows, also the ones from the nested tables, I commented out a few others I trued that did not give the desired results

what i want that it moves the complete rows, even if the row has a nested table and it dont count the rows in that table in the slice functionality

You can see my setup at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nokiko/naksv/21/)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) in all cases, or the [child selector (`>`)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) if you know your markup conditions:

```
$('#tblPropertyDetail tr:not(tr tr)').slice(0, 40).appendTo(".one");
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QnjhE/).  The alternative is:

```
$('#tblPropertyDetail > tr').slice(0, 40).appendTo(".one");
```

However, this may or may not work depending on your DOCTYPE, it depends if a `<tbody>` element it added in there for you (e.g. inferred in XHTML).  To be safe add the `<tbody>` yourself and do this:

```
$('#tblPropertyDetail > tbody > tr').slice(0, 40).appendTo(".one");
```

Comment: thanks I thought I had the top solution covered with $('#tblPropertyDetail tr:not(:has(tr))')  but yours worked perfect

Answer (score 1):

`$('#tableID > * > tr, #tableID > tr')`

just remember that * because <del>JavaScript</del> the browser automatically adds tbody elements.

EDIT:
Corrected a mistake about the tbody elements being added automatically.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't automatically add anything, it's the DOCTYPE that determines if it's inferred by the parser.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is a bit late and jQuery has evolved since, but there is now a better way to do it, just call children() ! :)

```
$('#tblPropertyDetail').children().appendTo(".one");
```

You can even add a selector to the `children()` method.

[Here's the doc about children() in jQuery.](http://api.jquery.com/children/).